# SQLPLUS writes ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿ to csv file when finds a data in other languages than English

Tags: csv, multilingual

I am trying to export the data from the Oracle table to csv file. The table has one of the column defined as CLOB data type and with data stored in multiple languages.

For instance,

```
create table test1
( col1 number,
col2 clob);

Insert into test1 values ( 1, '使用 Excel 数据挖掘外接程序执行购物篮分析');

select * from test1;
```

Executed and screenshot taken from SQL Developer:
[image]

When I ran the below script from SQLPlus

```
set echo off
set newpage none
set feedback off
set pages 0
spool C:\Users\venkat\Desktop\data.csv
select 'col1,col2' from dual;
select col1||',' || col2
from test1; 
spool off;
```

The data in the file appears like this

> col1,col2
>   1,¿¿ Excel ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿

Looking forward for some help in this forum. I want to see the data as it is in the database.

Edit: Apologies, I should have mentioned Environment as Windows.

More information on this NLS language parameter here

```
Select * from nls_database_parameters
 where parameter IN ('NLS_LANGUAGE','NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');
```

And the result of the says

> NLS_LANGUAGE  AMERICAN
>   NLS_CHARACTERSET  AL32UTF8
>   NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET    AL16UTF16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the `NLS_LANG` environment variable in order to tell SQL*Plus what character encoding to use; specify a character encoding which can represent the expected characters. See for example "[Running SQL](https://serverfault.com/questions/369951/running-sqlplus-with-bash-causes-wrong-encoding)*Plus with bash causes wrong encoding" on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

In Bash you would set an environment variable like this:

```
 export NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8"
```

On Windows with `cmd.exe` you would say

```
 set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
```

Comment: Hello Alex, Thanks for your reply, I could not really set the NLS_LANG with the above  statement from command prompt after logging into my database user, It says > SP2-0735: unknown SET option beginning "NLS_LANG=A..."

Comment: What do you mean, "could not set"? You must set it using the correct syntax for your shell, _before_ running SQLPlus.

Comment: I updated the OP, with the environment and and NLS parameter, please check them once. I am getting > SP2-0735: unknown SET option beginning "NLS_LANG=A..." when executed the above set statement from sqlplus

Comment: @Venkat: You must set the _environment variable_ **before** running SQLPlus. You cannot do it within the SQLPlus session.